# Adding a class to all the images within a <div> using javascript & vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I want to add a class to all the images within particular `<div>` using javascript.

I have made this code that adds a class to all the images in the webpage:

```
$(function(){
    $('img').addClass('posts');
});
```

But i want to add it only for a particular `<div>`.

And I need a different version that excludes the images from adding class within a `<div>`

How is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please, use `find`, it's better based on best practices of performance using jquery.

`$('#your_div').find('img').addClass('your-class')`

Comment: Good answer, this should be used.

Comment: How do I use 'find' to apply a class to all the images in the webpage?

Comment: If you need in ALL images, you don't need the find, but in case of images inside a particular `div`, `find` works because jQuery creates an array of all elements this way and you can apply anything that jQuery allows you to

Answer (score 3):

In pure javascript as asked:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('div.div1 img');
  [].forEach.call(imgs, function(element, index, array) {
    
    // add a new class
    element.classList.add("myclass");
    
    // ..or remove old class
    element.classList.remove("oldClass");
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <img src="" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" class="oldClass">
    <img src="" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" class="oldClass">
    <img src="" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" class="oldClass">
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <img src="" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
    <img src="" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
    <img src="" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
</div>
<div class="div3">
    <img src="" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
    <img src="" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
    <img src="" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've got more than enough responses to the first part of your question. As for the second, you can you use the `:not` pseudo-selector:

```
$(':not(#myDiv) > img').addClass('otherClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add more selectors in your function, like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.particular-div img').addClass('posts');
});
```

All the images inside `.particular-div` will add the class 'posts' to it.

Comment: how do I exclude a Div from adding a class using this?

Answer (score 0):

give the div an id and do this

```
$(function(){
    $('#myDiv img').addClass('posts');
});
```

Comment: how do I exclude a Div from adding a class using this?

Comment: this will only add class to all your image inside the div it will not add class for the div or any other elements

Comment: no, i want to add a class to all the images in the webpage except the ones inside a particular div.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have a way to specifically reference the `div` that you want to target and then target all of the images within that `div`.

For example, if you div had a particular ID, you can do something like this:

```
$('#divID img').addClass('posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add that particular div an ID:

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="myDiv" />
```

**JS CODE**

```
$(function(){
    $('#myDiv img').addClass('posts');
});
```

Comment: how do I exclude a Div from adding a class using this?

Answer (score -1):

Using the `.find()` should be used for filtering.

You can refer to this page to see the performance differences:http://jsperf.com/jquery-child-selector-vs-find/3

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/11/

HTML Example

```
<div id="someDiv">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="display: none">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="display: none">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#someDiv').find('img').addClass('showIMG')
```